# Accessing an enum type to create an object through inheritance

Tags: java, user-interface, inheritance, enums

My assignment is to use take an old lab we created an wrap a GUI around it, simple enough.. I have no problem creating the GUI or inheriting variables to create different objects but one object requires an Enum type in its parameters and i seem to be having a tough time assigning an enum type to the object even though the compiler doesn't complain so maybe you guys can help me out.

Manager class containing the enum class :

```
public enum Department {

    PAYROLL, PRODUCTION, ACCOUNTING, RESEARCH, MARKETING;

    public static Department getRandomDepartment() {
        Department[] d = Department.values();
        int size = Department.values().length;

        return d[r.nextInt(size)];
    }
};
```

there is a mutator method setDepartment that can be utilized but i am not sure how to instantiate it.

```
public void setDepartment(Department d) {
    department = d;
}
```

heres my Add manager method in my GUI class :

```
if(command.equals("Add Manager")){
        m_name = inputName.getText();
        m_num = inputNum.getText();
        m_year = Integer.parseInt(inputHire.getText());
        m_yearlyPay = Double.parseDouble(inputYearly.getText());


        if(inputDepartment.equals("Payroll") || inputDepartment.equals("payroll")){

             Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.PAYROLL);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(inputDepartment.equals("Production") || inputDepartment.equals("production")){
            Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.PRODUCTION);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(inputDepartment.equals("Accounting") || inputDepartment.equals("accounting")){
            Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.ACCOUNTING);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(inputDepartment.equals("Research") || inputDepartment.equals("research")){
             Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.RESEARCH);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(inputDepartment.equals("Marketing") || inputDepartment.equals("marketing")){
             Manager temp = new   Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.MARKETING);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }



    }
```

theres obviously something wrong with my method because when i input the department through the GUI it doesn't recognize the department i added, any thoughts on what my next step should be?

Comment: `f.equals("Foo")||f.equals("foo")` can be rewritten as `f.equalsIgnoreCase("Foo")` (unless you want to exclude cases like `"fOo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums always provide a `valueOf(String)` static factory which could help you I think.

i.e

`Manager.Department.valueOf("PAYROLL")` will return a `Manager.Department.PAYROLL`

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have fixed the problem and like always its something simple but thats coding for you lol,

i forgot to instantiate a string variable to act as a holder for the GUI so when i was inputting the department the string was going nowhere so it wasn't recognizing the department.

the working code is now :

```
if(command.equals("Add Manager")){
        m_name = inputName.getText();
        m_num = inputNum.getText();
        m_year = Integer.parseInt(inputHire.getText());
        m_yearlyPay = Double.parseDouble(inputYearly.getText());
        department = inputDepartment.getText(); 


        if(department.equalsIgnoreCase("Payroll")){

             Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.PAYROLL);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(department.equalsIgnoreCase("Production")){
            Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.PRODUCTION);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(department.equalsIgnoreCase("Accounting")){
            Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.ACCOUNTING);
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(department.equalsIgnoreCase("Research")){
             Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.RESEARCH);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }
        if(department.equalsIgnoreCase("Marketing")){
             Manager temp = new Manager(m_name,m_num,m_year,m_yearlyPay,Manager.Department.MARKETING);
             System.out.println(temp);
        }



    }
```

thanks for any input that was provided